# How to support multiple databases (postgresql) with Sidekiq server for the same project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, sidekiq

**I want Sidekiq to support multiple dynamic databases for the same project**

```rb
desc "Start sending the client invitation"

task "sidekiq:start", [:database] => :environment do |task, args|
  database = args[:database]
  config = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
     :adapter  => "postgresql",
     :host     => "localhost",
     :username => "postgres", 
     :password => 12345678,
    :database => database
  )

  puts "Start Running Sidkiq Server for new database instance - #{database}"
  system("bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -P tmp/pids/#{database}_sidekiq.pid")
  puts "Finished Running Sidkiq Server for new database instance - #{database}"

  puts "Finished connecting the client sidkiq"

end
```

```
rake sidekiq:start[hellodb]
```

Is there anything within sidekiq to pass database configuration dynamically ?

- It's always taking the database configuration from database.yml, even I used this establish_connection method. I want it to support database configurations dynamically.
- Basically, I am using multiple databases in my project depending on the sub domains. There, I am using same project but using multiple databases dynamically. So, I am looking for some ability that may allow using multiple sidekiq instances for different databases.

```
  config = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
     :adapter  => "postgresql",
     :host     => "localhost",
     :username => "postgres", 
     :password => 12345678,
    :database => database
  )
```

I will appreciate views on the same :)

Comment: I'm confused, where is this `config` variable being used? Because it is just a local variable

Comment: It’s not being used any where. It’s just a variable, I hve taken. Well, I am using establish_connection for configuring the database and it sets the fresh new connection of new database automatically. It reflects in the whole projects automatically on the fly. ( All the models etc calls from the new connected db automatically )

Comment: I want to run multiple sidekiq servers for different different databases dynamically. My app is based on the multi subdomain and using the same project instance but having different different database according to subdomain. So, I am not able to find any way of using sidekiq for dynamically connected db connection.

Comment: This seems like an architectural problem rather than Sidekiq. In actual fact, Sidekiq doesn't need to depend on your app to function, i.e. it can be an independent process not using any of your Rails code.
Your app sounds like it's a multi-tenant application, in which case(in my opinion), while creating a new job for Sidekiq to execute, you could as well pass in the identifier for the tenant and then within your job, fetch the connection for the tenant and use that connection.

Comment: It’s always taking the configuration from database.yml and I really don’t want that. I just want to pass my database configuration details manually and want sidekiq to work for this db.

Comment: Within your running app, aren't you setting the connection to be used for the different subdomains? If yes, then see my comment above as that should guide you to a solution.

Comment: Aha, Something came in mind as per your suggestion. I loved your idea  and you made my day :) Your one hint solved my problem, I guess :D. So @orelouwa, I will use just sidekiq and will paas any identifier or subdomain name with my background job that I want to execute and will make a new connection to database just before executing my function :D make sense ? :)

Comment: Yeah @oreoluwa, I saw your comment above and it’s exactly helped me and It will save my bulk of hours. [  I am wondering why it have not came in mind ] Well done Bro 